# Is it possible to check the number of tombstones using SSTable tools without shutting the node down?

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to check the number of tombstones within SSTable or SSTables without stopping a node (when using SSTable Tools)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the SSTable utilities are designed to be used offline.

Although it is possible to use tools like `sstabledump` without stopping Cassandra, in our experience operators run into unexpected issues when they introduce human errors.

For example, operators often make the mistake of running `sstabledump` as the `root` superuser instead of `cassandra`. This can cause files to be owned by `root` and causes the Cassandra process to crash so we recommend running the tools offline.

As a workaround, you can copy the SSTable data file (and all its component files to another server then run the tools there to avoid making errors in production. Cheers!